# Latitude value set to 0

Tags: android, google-maps

I set a value from MainActivity to Fragment, but the value become 0 in Fragment.
when I got log in moveToLocation(), value of latitude was 0, but when I got log in setLocation, value of latitude was correct passed value.
why is this?

MainActivity

```
MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
mapFragment.setLocation(111, 222, "abcAddress");
```

Fragment

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double mLatitude;
    private double mLongitude;
    private String mAddress;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            Log.d("", "You must update Google Maps.");
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        moveToLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_page, null);
    }

    public void setLocation(double latitude, double longitude, String address) {
        mLatitude = latitude;
        mLongitude = longitude;
        mAddress = address;
    }

    protected void moveToLocation() {
        CameraPosition location = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude)).zoom(15.5f)
                .bearing(0).tilt(25).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(location));
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude)).title(mAddress);
        marker.snippet("Snippet");
        mMap.addMarker(marker);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show more code of activity where you use replace, commit for fragment.

Comment: Are you creating new instance of `MapFragment` when trying to set Location ?

Comment: I don't use replace and commit in Activity.
other code in Activity doesn't have a relation with Fragment.

Comment: yes I created new instance of MapFragment

Comment: use `myFragment.setArguments(bundle);` to pass values when you show this fragment. show that code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create the  new instance of `MapFragment`.

To pass the values, set them in Argument while adding them in the Transaction :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putDouble("lat", latitude);
bundle.putDouble("long", longitude);
bundle.putString("address", address);
myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

And fetch the value in `onCreate()` like :

```
@Override
public View onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle mBundle = getArguments();

    if (mBundle != null) {
        String address = mBundle.getString("address");
        // Call method
        setLocation(mBundle.getDouble("lat"), mBundle.getDouble("long"), mBundle.getString("address"));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Hope it helps ツ

Comment: when you create an instance of MapFragment  for the first to show the MAP